# how to extract attribute value from mixed content from xml node

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I want to extract attribute value and assigned to the target xml node in xslt.

here is the node which holding mixed content

```
<oa:Expression expressionLanguage="_wcf:XPath">{_wcf.ap=IBM_External_Summary}/Order[BuyerIdentifier[(ExternalCustomerID='101234660')] 
 and BuyerIdentifier[(LogonID='anflee.jon.scott@gmail.com')] 
 and OrderStatus[(Status='M')] and StoreIdentifier[UniqueID=10051]]
```

could some one please let me how i can extract uniqueid,externalcustomerid,logonid and status.

Appreciate quick help.

Regards,
TJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that is **not** what [mixed content](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp) means. Secondly, you will have a hard time extracting the values, since they do not follow a common pattern (some are quoted, some are not, some are in round brackets, some in square).

Here's an example of using a named template to extract the value of `LogonID`:

```
<xsl:call-template name="extract">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="oa:Expression"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="label" select="'LogonID'"/>
</xsl:call-template>

...

<xsl:template name="extract">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="label"/>
    <xsl:param name="start">=&apos;</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="end">&apos;</xsl:param>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($string, concat($label, $start)), $end)" />
</xsl:template>
```

The same template can be used to extract the `ExternalCustomerID` and `Status` - but you will need to override the default `start` and `end` parameters when trying to extract `UniqueID`.

Comment: Thanks Micheal for pointing in right direction, i haven't used template but i have use same login which you provided. Many thanks